# Features scaling and mean normalization in a sparse matrix

Tags: machine-learning

Is it a good idea to perform features scaling and mean normalization on a sparse matrix? I have a matrix that is 70% sparse. Usually, features scaling and mean normalization improve the algorithm performance, but in the case of a sparse matrix, it adds a lot of non zero terms

Comment: There can't be any definitive answer on such question. Just try it in your case an see if it's faster...

Comment: @hivert "performance" means accuracy, not speed. Of course it's not faster. The question was how to make the tradeoff worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's important that the representation be sparse, in order to fit into memory for example, then you can't mean-normalize in the representation itself, no. It becomes completely dense and defeats the purpose.

Usually you push around the mean normalization math into another part of the formula or computation. Or you can just do the normalization as you access the elements, having previously computed the mean and variance.

Or you can pick an algorithm that doesn't need normalization, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If using scikit-learn you can just as below:

```python
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
scaler.fit(data)
```

Where you zero the mean to maintain sparsity as you can see on documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).